# Copy content of rich editor using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a rich text editor on my page, specifically this one:

https://github.com/davidroyer/vue2-editor

I need to copy the content of this editor into a different rich text editor on a different website.

I can do this manually, by selecting the content of the editor and copying it. When I paste into the target editor, I get the correct outcome: the text is formatted just like in the original editor, including links etc.

The problem is, I need to do the same using a "copy to clipboard" button. I have tried using this on the editor element directly:

```
editor.select();
document.execCommand("copy");
```

...but nothing ends up in the clipboard. I have tried putting the content into a regular input element and then doing the same thing above from that, but then when I paste in the target editor I get the raw HTML instead of the formatted text.

In short, if the content editor is this...

```
One line

Two lines
```

...I need it to paste into the target (I reiterate, on a different website) like this...

```
One line

Two lines
```

...and not like this:

```
<p>One line</p><p>Two lines</p>
```

Comment: From MDN: Note: document.execCommand() only returns true if it is invoked as part of a user interaction.   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document/execCommand

Comment: What does this mean? It happens on button click...

Comment: Try adding a debugging breakpoint to after `.select()` that way you can visually see if it's being selected. Then you will know if the issue lies in the `.select()` line or in the `.execCommand()` line.

Comment: @Zachiah I get an error in the console saying `editor.select() is not a function`. But if I `console.log(editor)` it logs the element correctly. I don't know what to make of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been working on this for a while, and I finally got it! The `vue2-editor` uses a `contenteditable` `div` for it's text editor. This is why you can't use the `.select()` method. Use

```js
console.log("selecting");
const e = document.querySelector("#app .ql-editor");
const textNode = e.childNodes[0];
const r = document.createRange();
const startIndex = 0;
r.setStart(e, startIndex);
r.setEnd(e, e.children.length);
const s = window.getSelection();
s.removeAllRanges();
s.addRange(r);
document.execCommand("copy")
```

I'm not a vue expert that's why I'm not using refs, I'm sure you should [here](https://codepen.io/zachiah/pen/LYbjELp?editors=1010) is an example that shows what I mean.